# iPad mini Wi-Fi in the UK

Tags: ipad, applications, maps

My iPad Mini does not have GPS capabilities.  I would like Maps to show my location.  Can I attach a Bluetooth GPS receiver to enable this functionality?  If so, will any Bluetooth GPS receiver work or will it have to be an Apple compatible one?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're on wifi network it will actually show your approximate location. Or are you interested in using it outdoors?

Comment: Outdoors on the moors